# Kotlin Incorrect null check warning

Tags: kotlin

```
class A
{
    val b:B
    val at:String
    init
    {
        b=B(this)
        at="A's text"
    }
}

class B(a:A)
{
    val bt:String
    init
    {
        bt= if(a.at!=null) a.at.replaceFirst("A's","B's") else "else's text"
    }

}
```

This code will generate a warning

> Condition 'a.at!=null' is always 'true'

but actually the condition 'a.at!=null' is always false.

Comment: `a.at`'s type is `String`, which is non-null (hint: `String?` is nullable, `String` is non-null). So what do you mean by "it is always false"?

Comment: Even `a.at` is non-null, the condition `a.at!=null` will be always false. Check the output of this code [link](https://pl.kotl.in/Sk1gv_L07)

Comment: Oh you mean this. The results depends on the sequence. If the two lines in `init` of `class A` swaps, then the result will be expected. I wonder if this is a bug in grammar analysis.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you initialize all properties in `init` block instead of in-place? Though this doesn't affect this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is already reported 3 years ago, as [KT-10455](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10455), "Kotlin allows use of class members before initialization, leading to runtime exceptions, including NPEs on non-null types".

For temporarily fix, you can just swap the two lines in `init` in `class A`, make sure `A.at` is defined before used.

```
class A
{
    val b:B
    val at:String
    init
    {
        at="A's text"
        b=B(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize variable `at` and then `b`:

```
class A
{
    val b:B
    val at:String
    init
    {
        at="A's text"
        b=B(this)

    }
}
```